# Firefox does not like .val in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, firefox

Works in IE, in Firefox the two fields are blank and **name** is undefined in EditUserRoles after it's assigned:

GetRows is called from the gridview, the calls editUserRoles

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
                    <ItemTemplate>                       
                        <input type="button" id="btnEditUserRoles" style="width:60px;"  onclick="GetRows(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)" value="Edit" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

<input type="text" disabled="disabled" id="txtAkoUserName" />
<input type="text" id="txtUserName" />

function GetRows(index) {
        var userGrid = document.getElementById('<%=gridUserRoles.ClientID%>');
        EditUserRoles(index, userGrid);
    }
function EditUserRoles(rowIndex, userGrid) {
    if (null != userGrid) {
        var userName = userGrid.rows[rowIndex].cells[0].innerText;
        var name = userGrid.rows[rowIndex].cells[1].innerText;
        LoadEditForm(userName, name);
}

function LoadEditForm(userName, name) {
    $("#txtAkoUserName").val(userName);
    $("#txtUserName").val(name);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Firefox does not support `innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.textContent). Just use jQuery to avoid these cross browser issues (that's what it is there for):

```
var userName = $(userGrid.rows[rowIndex].cells[0]).text();
var name = $(userGrid.rows[rowIndex].cells[1]).text();
```